# Using RSolve for recurrence equation

Tags: difference-equations

I'd like to use Mathematica to verify the solution to a recurrence equation. I have the following equation:

$Q_{k+1} = Q_k + \alpha(r_{k+1} - Q_k)$.

I also have a derivation showing how to obtain a solution for any $k$:

$Q_k = Q_{k-1} + \alpha(r_k - Q_{-1})$

$\ \ \ \ = \alpha r_k + (1 - \alpha)Q_{k-1}$

$\ \ \ \ = \alpha r_k + (1 - \alpha)\alpha r_{k-1} + (1 - \alpha)^2Q_{k-2}$

$\ \ \ \ = (1 - \alpha)^kQ_0 + \sum_{i=1}^k\alpha (1 - \alpha)^{k-i}r_i$,

where $Q_0$ is some arbitrary constant. However, when I use `RSolve`, I get a different answer.

```
RSolve[Q[k] == Q[k - 1] + \[Alpha] (Subscript[r, k] - Q[k - 1]), Q[k], k]
```

gives me the solution:

$(1 - \alpha)^{k-1}\mathbb{c}_1+(1-\alpha)^{-1+k}\sum_{K[1]=0}^{-1+k}(1-\alpha)^{-K[1]}\alpha r_{1+K[1]}.$

This is close but not exactly what I want. So what am I missing here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing the initial condition `Q[0] == Q0`.

```
Q[k] /. RSolve[{Q[k] == Q[k - 1] + α (Subscript[r, k] - Q[k - 1]), Q[0] == Q0}, 
    Q[k], k][[1]] // FullSimplify
```

> [image]

This is equivalent to

$$(1-\alpha )^k Q0+\sum _{K[1]=1}^k \alpha\ (1-\alpha )^{k-K[1]}\   r_{K[1]}$$

Comment: Great that works. I thought the $\mathbb{c}_1$ constant was the value for the initial condition, but I guess not. Do you know where it comes from if it's not the value for Q[0]?

Comment: @whaaswijk I do not know that.

Answer (score 5):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

Format[Q[k_]] := Subscript[Q, k];
Format[Q0] = Subscript[Q, 0];
```

Include the initial condition in [`RSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RSolve.html)

```
sol = (RSolve[
      {Q[k] == Q[k - 1] + \[Alpha] (Subscript[r, k] - Q[k - 1]), Q[0] == Q0},
      Q[k], k][[1]] // Simplify) /. K[1] -> i
```

[image]

Translate the index of summation

```
sol2 = ((sol /. Sum -> Inactive[Sum]) /.
    Inactive[Sum][expr_, {i, imin_, imax_}] :>
     Inactive[Sum][(expr /. i -> i - 1), {i, imin + 1, imax + 1}]) //
  Collect[#, Q0] &
```

[image]

Simplify the summation term

```
(sol3 = sol2 /. (expr1_ * Inactive[Sum][expr2_, {i, imin_, imax_}]) :> 
     Inactive[Sum][expr1*expr2, {i, imin, imax}]) // Activate
```

[image]

Comment: This is very nice, but it's using some advanced Mathematica magic that I'm not familiar with. I had no idea that you could do things like translating the index of summation. I'll have to look at the documentation to see exactly how this all works.

Comment: That was some deft use of Inactive and Collect.